# ng2-smart-table getAll() method

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to be able to retrieve all records from the table. I am using the localDatasource. But unfortunately using the below code, it is returning empty. Can someone advise?

```
  add($event) {
    $event.confirm.resolve($event.newData);
    this.source.getAll().then((data) => console.log(data));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this!

```
    let data = [];
    this.source.getAll().then(value => { 
        value.forEach(element => {
            data.push(element); 
        });;
    });
```